# How to put an array to DB (php, pdo)?

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, pdo

Need your help. Got some problems with putting an array's data to DB via php pdo. I'm amateur frond-end dev. that's quite far from backend, so there are no people except you to help me! In the DB table I've got some columns, among others "myActions" - need to put all the data from my inputs with the names name="action[]" to this column row by row.
In html code I have inputs' names like that:

```
<div id="field">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="field1" name="action[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" data-items="8"/>
    <button id="b1" class="btn add-more" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

In php file :

```
<?php
$incident_number = $_POST['incident_number'];
$incident_type = $_POST['incident_type'];
$incident_subject = $_POST['incident_subject'];
$incident_time = $_POST['incident_time'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$wasdone = $_POST['action'];
try {
/*** connect to SQLite database ***/
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:myDB2");
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
//echo 'Connected to database<br />';
/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$Log = date(DATE_RFC2822)."   Creation".PHP_EOL;
//echo $Log;
$sql = "INSERT INTO myData
(incident_number,incident_type,incident_subject,incident_time,status) values
(:incident_number,:incident_type,:incident_subject,:incident_time,:status);"
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':incident_number', $incident_number);
$query->bindParam(':incident_type', $incident_type);
$query->bindParam(':incident_subject', $incident_subject);
$query->bindParam(':incident_time', $incident_time);
$query->bindParam(':status', $status);

//$query->bindParam(':Log', $Log, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
//$query->execute(array(':NameImp'=>$NameImp));
// Close file db connection
$dbh = null;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
try {

 /*** connect to SQLite database ***/
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:myDB2");
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
//echo 'Connected to database<br />';
/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$Log = date(DATE_RFC2822)."   Creation".PHP_EOL;
//echo $Log;
$sql = "INSERT INTO myActions (action) values (:wasdone);";
foreach ($wasdone as $key => &$value) {  //pass $value as a reference to the array item
$query->bindParam($key, $value);  // bind the variable to the statement
}
//$query->bindParam(':Log', $Log, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
//$query->execute(array(':NameImp'=>$NameImp));
// Close file db connection
$dbh = null;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP's [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which joins the elements of an array into a single string, delimited by a custom substring.

You can later use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn your string back into a workable array when you query it from the database.

*Note: while this is a quick solution that could work for your use case, if the arrays in the dataset become too large or your project increases in complexity, you should look into [data normalization](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/abhijit_desai/2010/09/07/noramlization/) and make additional tables for your `actions` array elements as good data management practice.*